# Can't put double SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Getting error, the method put double is undefined for this type of sharedPreferences editor.Eclipse is given one quick fix add cast to editor, but when i do that its still given errors, Why cant i put double.

The code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editBl.getText().toString())) {
        numberOfBl = 0;
    } else {
        numberOfBl = Integer.parseInt(editBl.getText().toString();

    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editSt.getText().toString())) {
        tonOfSt = 0;
    } else {
        tonOfSt = Double.parseDouble(editSt.getText().toString());

    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            "SavedTotals", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putInt("savedBl", numberOfBl);
    editor.putDouble("savedSt", tonOfSt);


    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: could you please specify what error you've got?

Comment: Look at first line of the question

Comment: i wonder how comes that android guys didn't implement putDouble in API?

Answer (score 360):

Those who suggested to use *putFloat* and *getFloat* are unfortunately very wrong. Casting a double to a float can result in

1. Lost precision
2. Overflow
3. Underflow
4. Dead kittens

Those suggesting a *toString* and *parseString* are not wrong, but it's an inefficient solution.

The correct way of dealing with this is to convert the double to its 'raw long bits' equivalent and store that long. When you're reading the value, convert back to double.

Because the two data types have the same size you don't lose precision and you won't cause an {over,under}flow.

```java
Editor putDouble(final Editor edit, final String key, final double value) {
   return edit.putLong(key, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value));
}

double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs, final String key, final double defaultValue) {
return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key, Double.doubleToLongBits(defaultValue)));
}
```

Alternatively you can write the getter as:

```java
double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs, final String key, final double defaultValue) {
if ( !prefs.contains(key))
        return defaultValue;

return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key, 0));
}
```

Comment: A putDouble method would still be nice and consistent though with other API within the android ecosystem (like parceable and bundles). A typical case of Google being fast and sloppy again.

Comment: why saving it as string is inefficient?

Comment: @KKO The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. So it takes only 4-bytes. But if you store that `double` value as a string then you ruin your storage and make it a wreckage!!

Comment: Does passing the arguments as final in the above method declaration makes any difference?

Comment: @anant a final parameter cannot be changed by the method. Think of it as a promise that it won't store a different value to the SharedPreferences. If my method has no reason to change a parameter, I declare it as final.

Comment: I'm getting the following crash: "java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Long". The code causing it is: "return Double.longBitsToDouble(pref.getLong(qualifiedPrefKey(key), Double.doubleToLongBits(defaultValue)));"

Comment: I found that there are `Double.doubleToLongBits()` and `Double.doubleToRawLongBits()`, what's the difference? Thank you.

Answer (score 43):

Kotlin extension way (much more pretty than using weird utils classes or whatever)

```
fun SharedPreferences.Editor.putDouble(key: String, double: Double) =
    putLong(key, java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double))

fun SharedPreferences.getDouble(key: String, default: Double) =
    java.lang.Double.longBitsToDouble(getLong(key, java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits(default)))
```

Comment: Great, I was exactly thinking about putting this here. Thanks!

Comment: here how to get data in variable? anyone help me

Answer (score 19):

What I did was save the preference as a String:

```
getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("double", "0.01").commit();
```

and then to retrieve the double, simply use Double.parseDouble:

```
Double.parseDouble(getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("double", "0.01"));
```

Comment: You're wasting storage. It's also much slower than the `doubleToRawLongBits` method that is already mentioned. This is the *wrong* way, not because it won't work, but because it's very inefficient.

Comment: @copolii Academically, sure. Practically, in industry, it really doesn't make enough of a difference to matter in 99% of cases and in fact this is probably more readable and easier to grasp when bringing on someone new.

Comment: @DennisL #PracticalDev

Answer (score 9):

You could always implement SharedPreferences and wrap the android implementation.

```
package com.company.sharedpreferences;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;


import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class EnhancedSharedPreferences implements SharedPreferences {

    public static class NameSpaces {
        public static String MY_FUN_NAMESPACE = "MyFunNameSpacePrefs";
    }

    public static EnhancedSharedPreferences getPreferences(String prefsName) {
        return new EnhancedSharedPreferences(SomeSingleton.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(prefsName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    }

    private SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;

    public EnhancedSharedPreferences(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
        _sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
    }

    //region Overrides

    @Override
    public Map<String, ?> getAll() {
        return _sharedPreferences.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String key, String defValue) {
        return _sharedPreferences.getString(key, defValue);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getStringSet(String key, Set<String> defValues) {
        return _sharedPreferences.getStringSet(key, defValues);
    }

    @Override
    public int getInt(String key, int defValue) {
        return _sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defValue);
    }

    @Override
    public long getLong(String key, long defValue) {
        return _sharedPreferences.getLong(key, defValue);
    }

    @Override
    public float getFloat(String key, float defValue) {
        return _sharedPreferences.getFloat(key, defValue);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue) {
        return _sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defValue);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(String key) {
        return _sharedPreferences.contains(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Editor edit() {
        return new Editor(_sharedPreferences.edit());
    }

    @Override
    public void registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener) {
        _sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener) {
        _sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

    //endregion

    //region Extension

    public Double getDouble(String key, Double defValue) {
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(_sharedPreferences.getLong(key, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(defValue)));
    }

    //endregion

    public static class Editor implements SharedPreferences.Editor {

        private SharedPreferences.Editor _editor;

        public Editor(SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
            _editor = editor;
        }

        private Editor ReturnEditor(SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
            if(editor instanceof Editor)
                return (Editor)editor;
            return new Editor(editor);
        }

        //region Overrides

        @Override
        public Editor putString(String key, String value) {
            return ReturnEditor(_editor.putString(key, value));
        }

        @Override
        public Editor putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values) {
            return ReturnEditor(_editor.putStringSet(key, values));
        }

        @Override
        public Editor putInt(String key, int value) {
            return ReturnEditor(_editor.putInt(key, value));
        }

        @Override
        public Editor putLong(String key, long value) {
            return ReturnEditor(_editor.putLong(key, value));
        }

        @Override
        public Editor putFloat(String key, float value) {
            return ReturnEditor(_editor.putFloat(key, value));
        }

        @Override
        public Editor putBoolean(String key, boolean value) {
            return ReturnEditor(_editor.putBoolean(key, value));
        }

        @Override
        public Editor remove(String key) {
            return ReturnEditor(_editor.remove(key));
        }

        @Override
        public Editor clear() {
            return ReturnEditor(_editor.clear());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean commit() {
            return _editor.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void apply() {
            _editor.apply();
        }

        //endregion

        //region Extensions

        public Editor putDouble(String key, double value) {
            return new Editor(_editor.putLong(key, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value)));
        }

        //endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I wish I had seen this before I started typing.

Wouldn't it be more efficient to just return 'this' in the editor methods?
It saves you from calling the 'instanceof' method. Or have you tried that and it caused problems?

Answer (score 0):

Check this gist https://gist.github.com/john1jan/b8cb536ca51a0b2aa1da4e81566869c4

I have created a Preference Utils class that will handle all the cases.

Its Easy to Use

Storing into preference

```
PrefUtils.saveToPrefs(getActivity(), PrefKeys.USER_INCOME, income);
```

Getting from preference

```
Double income = (Double) PrefUtils.getFromPrefs(getActivity(), PrefKeys.USER_INCOME, new Double(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can convert the double value in a bit representation of the specified floating-point value as Long and then save that bit representation in shared preference with **putLong()** method.
When you want to fetch that value from shared preference just convert it to Double value with **Double.fromBits()** method and you will have a double value with no precision loss.
You can read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html).

Here is an example where I use latitude and longitude as a double value within shared preference:

```
    val lat: Double = 40.23244412709637
    val lng: Double = 14.280891281901097
    
     private fun saveFetchedLocation(lat: Double, lng: Double) {
            val sharedPreference: SharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                SHARED_PREF,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
            )
            val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreference.edit()
            editor.apply {
                putLong("lat_value", lat.toBits())
                putLong("lng_val", lng.toBits())
     
            Log.i("Tag", "LONG_BITS: "+ " Lat: " + lat.toBits() + " Lng: " + lng.toBits())
    
            }.apply()
    
        }
    
    private fun loadPreferences() {
            val sharedPreference: SharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                SHARED_PREF,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
            )
            val lat_double: Double = Double.fromBits(sharedPreference.getLong("lat_value", 1))
            val lng_double: Double = Double.fromBits(sharedPreference.getLong("lng_val", 1))
    
            Log.i("Tag", "FINAL_DOUBLE: $lat_double and $lng_double")
    
        }
```

Logcat result:

```
//bit representation of the specified floating-point values as Long
I/Tag: LONG_BITS:  Lat: 4630859030446343002 Lng: 4624229045136719443 

//converted double values with no precision loss
I/Tag: FINAL_DOUBLE: 40.23244412709637 and 14.280891281901097
```