# How to return a double from SharedPreferences (Android)

Tags: java, android, double, sharedpreferences

I apparently do not have enough reputation to add a comment and request clarification on a topic, so I will have to re-add the question here.

According to the link: 
[Can't put double SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319237/cant-put-double-sharedpreferences)

The top rated answer has the best way to return a double from sharedpreferences as:

```
double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs,
                 final String key, final double defaultValue) {
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key, Double.doubleToLongBits(defaultValue)));
}
```

I am having trouble identifying what goes into the parameter `defaultValue`. Is this parameter supposed to be a variable doing in (like a double) that the original value was? Is it unique to my class? What is it?

If possible, would someone mind giving an example so I can understand it a bit better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

defaultValue is what you get when there is no such key defined as "key" in shared pref, example if you are retrieving data for first time and you didn't write a value for your key it will return defaultValue.

```
double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs, final String key, final double defaultValue)
{ return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key, Double.doubleToLongBits(defaultValue)));}
```

lets say you have put 542.3 into myDouble

```
getDouble("myDouble" , 5.0); // will return 542.3
```

but if you haven't put anything into myDouble

```
getDouble("myDouble" , 5.0); // will return 5
```

The common use, is when keep track of data, and your users can clear that data (imagine a highscore in a game) so you don't want to check if it exists, instead you launch it with default value.

```
getDouble("highscore" , 0.0); // will return highscore if exists otherwise will return 0
```

Comment: Flawless answer. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 2):

Set and Get preferences as string....

```
latitude = location.getLatitude();
longitude = location.getLongitude();

//save last valid position
String mLastLatitude = latitude.toString();
myPreferences.setLastLatitude(mLastLatitude);

String mLastLongitude = longitude.toString();
myPreferences.setLastLongitude(mLastLongitude);

//get last position 
lastLatitude = Double.valueOf(myPreferences.getLastLatitude());
lastLongitude = Double.valueOf(myPreferences.getLastLongitude());
```