# Android - How to save highscore of double value?

Tags: java, numbers, save, double

I have a double value which is in the range of 0-1. The new highscore value should be the lesser value of the two. Basically for example: if user A had a previous highscore of 0.6, and he just scored 0.4, the new highscore should be 0.4. Please be descriptive as I'm a beginner, thank you.

EDIT: Sorry I didn't make it descriptive enough, but I want the highscore to be saved and be able to be accessed again. So, if the user exits the app and revisits, it still shows the highscore.

Comment: double highScore = Math.min(oldHighScore, newScore);

Comment: Please don't post answers as a comment.

Comment: @LanceJava sorry I didn't make it descriptive enough, but I want the score to be saved. So, when the user exits the app and revisits, the highscore is still there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll want to use Shared Preferences to store the value for later: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html, and then check this when you go to save it.

Here is sample code so you can call `writeHighScore(score)`,  and it will save it if it is lower than the previously saved high score:

```
void writeHighScore(float score)
{
    if (score < getOldHighScore())
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putFloat("highscore", score);
        editor.commit();
    }
}    


float getOldHighScore()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPref.getFloat("highscore", 1);
}
```

I used a float here instead of a double. If you want to store a double with shared preferences, you'll need to convert it to and from a Long, like here: [Can't put double SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319237/cant-put-double-sharedpreferences)