# Hello, I am making an android quiz to go to the result activity when questions are completed but its not going to result activity

Tags: android, android-activity

My project code is give here  and in this i want to go to the result activity when my questions are over. It goes to result activity only when time is up but not when the questions are over. What should i implement in if(<20) line code to go to result page.

**MyQuizActivity:**

```
public class MyQuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private QuestionBank mQuestionBank = new QuestionBank();

        private TextView mScoreView;
        private TextView times;//For Timer in Quiz
        private TextView mQuestionView;
        private Button mButtonChoice1;
        private Button mButtonChoice2;
        private Button mButtonChoice3;
        private Button mButtonChoice4;


        private String mAnswer;
        private double mScore = 0;
        private int mQuestionNumber = 0;

    private int count_correct_answer =0;
    private int count_wrong_answer=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_quiz);

    mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);
    mButtonChoice4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice4);
    updateQuestion();

    // Set the timer for Quiz
    times = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
// method which will set the things up for our game
    times.setText("00:02:00");
// A timer of 20 minutes to play for, with an interval of 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
    CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(1200000, 1000);
    timer.start();
    //Code Ends here

    if (mQuestionNumber< 20) {
// if questions are not over then do this

                mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionBank.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));

                //set all buttons Blue for next question
                mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                mButtonChoice2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                mButtonChoice3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                mButtonChoice4.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                updateQuestion();

    }
    else {
// if over do this
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyQuizActivity.this,
                ResultActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putDouble("mScore", mScore); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


    //Start of Button Listener for Button1
    mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //My Logic for Button goes in here
            if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                //Post Question Delay Code
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Code Ends hers
                        mScore = mScore + 02.00;
                        count_correct_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        updateQuestion();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                //This line of code is optional
                Toast.makeText(MyQuizActivity.this, "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else {
                //Post Question Delay Code
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Code Ends hers
                        mScore = (mScore - 00.66);
                        count_wrong_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        updateQuestion();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                //This line of code is optional
                Toast.makeText(MyQuizActivity.this, "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    //End of Button Listener for Button1

    //Start of Button Listener for Button2
    mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //My Logic for Button goes in here
            if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                //Post Question Delay Code
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Code Ends hers
                        mScore = mScore + 02.00;
                        count_correct_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        updateQuestion();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                mButtonChoice2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                //This line of code is optional
                Toast.makeText(MyQuizActivity.this, "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else {
                //Post Question Delay Code
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Code Ends hers
                        mScore = (mScore - 00.66);
                        count_wrong_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        updateQuestion();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                mButtonChoice2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                //This line of code is optional
                Toast.makeText(MyQuizActivity.this, "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    //End of Button Listener for Button2

    //Start of Button Listener for Button3
    mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //My Logic for Button goes in here
            if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                //Post Question Delay Code
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Code Ends hers
                        mScore = mScore + 02.00;
                        count_correct_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        updateQuestion();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                mButtonChoice3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                //This line of code is optional
                Toast.makeText(MyQuizActivity.this, "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else {
                //Post Question Delay Code
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Code Ends hers
                        mScore = (mScore - 00.66);
                        count_wrong_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        updateQuestion();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                mButtonChoice3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                //This line of code is optional
                Toast.makeText(MyQuizActivity.this, "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    //End of Button Listener for Button3

    //Start of Button Listener for Button4
    mButtonChoice4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //My Logic for Button goes in here
            if (mButtonChoice4.getText() == mAnswer) {
                //Post Question Delay Code
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Code Ends hers
                        mScore = mScore + 02.00;
                        count_correct_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        updateQuestion();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                mButtonChoice4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                //This line of code is optional
                Toast.makeText(MyQuizActivity.this, "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else {
                //Post Question Delay Code
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Code Ends hers
                        mScore = (mScore - 00.66);
                        count_wrong_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        updateQuestion();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                mButtonChoice4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                //This line of code is optional
                Toast.makeText(MyQuizActivity.this, "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    //End of Button Listener for Button4
}

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            times.setText("Time is up");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyQuizActivity.this,
                    ResultActivity.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putDouble("mScore", + mScore); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            startActivity(intent);

            Bundle c = new Bundle();
            c.putInt("count_correct_answer", + count_correct_answer); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(c); // Put your Correct Answer score to your next
            startActivity(intent);

            Bundle d = new Bundle();
            d.putInt("count_wrong_answer", + count_wrong_answer); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(d); // Put your Wrong Answer score to your next
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();
        }
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format(
                    "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            .toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            .toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            times.setText(hms);
        }
    }



        private void updateQuestion(){
            mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionBank.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionBank.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionBank.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionBank.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice4.setText(mQuestionBank.getChoice4(mQuestionNumber));

            mAnswer = mQuestionBank.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
            mQuestionNumber++;
        }
        private void updateScore(double point){
            mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);
        }

    }
```

**ResultActivity:**

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        //Showing Test Result
        TextView textResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResult);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        Double mScore = b.getDouble("mScore", 0.0);
        textResult.setText("Your Score is :  " + mScore + " .   Thanks for playing my game.");
        //Code Ends here

        //Showing Correct Answers
        TextView correctanswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correctanswer);
        Bundle c = getIntent().getExtras();
        int count_correct_answer = c.getInt("count_correct_answer", 0 );
        correctanswer.setText("No. of Correct answers are :  " + count_correct_answer + " . ");
        //Code Ends Here

        //Showing Wrong Answers
        TextView wronganswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wronganswer);
        Bundle d = getIntent().getExtras();
        int count_wrong_answer = d.getInt("count_wrong_answer", 0 );
        wronganswer.setText("No. of Wrong answers are :  " + count_wrong_answer + " . ");
        //Code Ends Here

    }

    public void playagain(View o) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyQuizActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It goes to result activity only when time is up but not when the questions are over.

This is because onCreate() is called only once when the activity is started, so this code

```
if (mQuestionNumber< 20) {
         mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionBank.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));

            //set all buttons Blue for next question
            mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            mButtonChoice2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            mButtonChoice3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            mButtonChoice4.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            updateQuestion();

}
else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyQuizActivity.this,
            ResultActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putDouble("mScore", mScore); // Your score
    intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

runs only when activity is started and after that you are just updating the questions and choices, the else part is not running actually.

So what you can do is check question count in updateQuestion() and call result activity from there.

Comment: Thank you ,  I put this whole if  else condition in update Question() in the end

Comment: How can i add highscore in double format instead of int format in result activity..  My code of ResultActivity is here..

Comment: //Saving the High Score
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("GAME_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Double highScore = settings.getDouble("HIGH_SCORE", 00);

        if (mScore > highScore){
            highScoreLabel.setText("High Score : " +mScore);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putDouble("HIGH_SCORE", mScore);
            editor.commit();
        }
        else {
            highScoreLabel.setText("High Score : " + highScore);
        }

Comment: If this helped accept this answer. And you can't use putDouble() directly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319237/cant-put-double-sharedpreferences) may help

Comment: when i use int instead of double of int mScore it works fine and double condition it shows error

Comment: Check documentation for [SharedPreferences.Editor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html), there is no putDouble() method.

Comment: than what should i do to save my decimal Score in highscores

Comment: When i start the app and click back then it closes as usual but when i click play again in Result Activity it goes to Main Activity but when i click back in Main Activity it goes directly to Result Page means back button is not exiting the app after it comes back from result page, Thank you for your previous help, and hope you can see what the problem actually is...

Comment: call finish() in your ResultActivity when you press play again

Comment: i already tried using finish(); in play again but it won't worked for me

Comment: I tried this in result activity// Code for Play Again
    public void playagain(View o) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ResultActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
    //On Pressing Back Button Taking to the Quiz Start Activity(Main Activity)
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ResultActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    //Code end for back pressed

Answer (score 0):

you add more than one bundle so i think its not working.try this..

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MyQuizActivity.this,
                    ResultActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("mScore", +mScore); //put score
            intent.putExtras("count_correct_answer", +count_correct_answer); // Put your Correct Answer score to your next
            intent.putExtras("count_wrong_answer", +count_wrong_answer); // Put your Wrong Answer score to your next
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `finish()` before - `startactivity(your intent)`.. Your current condition finished the activity after starting it...