# Unable to save and retreive Double from storage

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I always get this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

```
  val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
  val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
  var myLongitude = 36.892672
  editor.putDouble("longitude", myLongitude)
  editor.apply()
```

The error is from here:

```
val savedLongitude : Double = sharedPreferences.getDouble("longitude", 0.0)
```

I have these methods:

```
 fun SharedPreferences.Editor.putDouble(key: String, double: Double) =
          putLong(key, java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double))

  fun SharedPreferences.getDouble(key: String, default: Double) =
          java.lang.Double.longBitsToDouble(getLong(key, java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits(default)))
```

My goal is to save a double value to SharedPref and then retrieve it

Comment: you save and retrieve value with different keys

Comment: also, i do not know how you do this in kotlin, but in java you suppose to call .commit after putString(key, value)

Comment: sorry i edited the quuestion

Comment: ok, what about String.valueOf(double) instead double.toString?

Comment: yes I tried that before and i still get the same error

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `SharedPreferences.putFloat()` ? Do you really need that precision here?

Comment: Your code just changed from reading ``String``s to whatever Eugene Troyanskii posted in their answer. Whatever you're actually doing, you've stored an ``Int`` with that key and now you're trying to read the value back as something else

Comment: If you're trying out different things then ``remove`` the current value from the ``SharedPreferences``, if you're always reading it before you write a new one then you're never going to update it because you hit the read exception first

Comment: I am not using an int anywhere

Comment: you haven't posted your stacktrace, but assuming you're getting that exception when you're reading a value from the ``SharedPreferences``, that means your key is pulling a stored ``Int`` and trying to cast it to a ``String`` or ``Long`` or whatever. Which means an ``Int`` was stored with that key at some point, which is why I'm saying to do a ``remove()`` call to clear it away (just running the app with it once is enough, then you can delete it from your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use much elegant approach. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18098090/5422725 this is variant for java. But in case you use kotlin, you could use extension to make it mor eclear.

Kotlin extension way (much more pretty than using weird utils classes or whatever)

```
fun SharedPreferences.Editor.putDouble(key: String, double: Double) =
    putLong(key, java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double))

fun SharedPreferences.getDouble(key: String, default: Double) =
    java.lang.Double.longBitsToDouble(getLong(key, java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits(default)))
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45412036/5422725)

Comment: Yes, i have seen this before but i get a similar error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

Answer (score 0):

do this to store double value to preferences

```
 final Editor editor = getPreferences().edit();
 editor.putLong(key, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value));
 editor.apply();
```

Double.doubleToRawLongBits() is

> Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value
> according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "double format" bit layout,
> preserving Not-a-Number (NaN) values.

To get double vlaues from preferences use this

```
Double.longBitsToDouble(getPreferences().getLong(key, Double.doubleToLongBits(defValue)));
```

Comment: Yes, i have seen this before but i get a similar error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

Comment: what value you are passing to the `value`?

Comment: a `Double` value

Comment: post the code that how you are doing and at which line this error is throwing

Comment: See edited answer to how to get double value from preferences